# How to check date within two given dates and return true or false

Tags: javascript

I am trying to verify whether the given date is within the two dates. I tried based on online resources I find using below methods whatever I tried code returning False, so could someone please let me know how we can achieve this. Thanks

```
// *For example* - Datetocheck = today's date
                Startdate = '09/05/2022' 
                Enddate ='31/05/2022'
    
         var TodayDate = new Date();
           //var date = now.toLocaleDateString();
        var dd = String(TodayDate.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        var mm = String(TodayDate.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
        var yyyy = TodayDate.getFullYear();
        TodayDate = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;

    if(dateStart!=null&&dateStart!=undefined){     
            var year=dateStart.getFullYear();
            var month=(dateStart.getMonth()+1);
            var day=dateStart.getDate();       
     var startdate = day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    }
    
    if(dateEnd!=null&&dateEnd!=undefined){
            var year1=dateEnd.getFullYear();
            var month1=(dateEnd.getMonth()+1);
            var day1=dateEnd.getDate();      
       var enddate = day1 + '/' + month1 + '/' + year1;
    }
    
     if(TodayDate > startdate && TodayDate < enddate {
          return true;
         // alert("Within the range");
      }else{
           return false;
          // alert("Outside the range");     
      }
```

Comment: If you change your date formats to YYYY/MM/DD, you can simply make a Date object with the date string (`new Date('2022/09/05')`) and compare the dates directly (`dateToCheck > startDate && dateToCheck < endDate`)

Comment: It's because you're comparing strings and not the timestamps themselves

Comment: @chris coerdes - Thanks for your help. I tried changing the date format as you suggested above and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing strings. If you used YYYY-MM-DD order, that would work, but since you're using DD/MM/YYYY order, it doesn't. The strings are compared "alphabetically" (including non-letters being ordered the way they are in the character set), which means that, for example, the 20th of any month will be "greater than" the 10th of any month, even if the two months are in the opposite order within the year and/or the dates are years apart, just because 2 comes after 1.

I would just use Date objects directly.

```
const startDate = new Date(2022,4,9); // 0=January, so May=4
const endDate = new Date(2022,4,31);
let todayDate = new Date();
if (startDate <= todayDate && todayDate <= endDate) {
   console.log("In range.");
}
```

Also, above I'm doing a test and then logging a message if the test is true, but if you want a function that just returns true or false, you don't need an `if` statement. Just return the value of the boolean expression itself:

```
return startDate <= todayDate && todayDate <= endDate;
```

Comment: The word you're looking for is "lexicographically".

Comment: Sure, but probably OP wouldn't have this question if that was a familiar word to them..

Comment: @Mark Reed, Thank you for your time in helping me out on the issue. I tried changing the date format 'yyyy/mm/dd' and it worked. Many thanks for your help again on this.